# tag synonym for tag "standards"

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

Tag synonyms:

- [standards](/questions/tagged/standards) 1460 questions
- [standards-compliance](/questions/tagged/standards-compliance) 205 questions
- [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) 357 questions

Notes:

1. I would like [standards-compliance](/questions/tagged/standards-compliance) and [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) to be remapped to [standards](/questions/tagged/standards), or if [standards](/questions/tagged/standards) isn't a synonym just remap [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) to [standards-compliance](/questions/tagged/standards-compliance) (it's remapping a tag with more questions to a tag with less questions, but I think [standards-compliance](/questions/tagged/standards-compliance) is more appropriciate)
2. I deduce that [standards-compliance](/questions/tagged/standards-compliance) and [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) are synonyms from the [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) tag wiki

Comment: BTW, what's your question exactly?

Comment: @Bhuro tag synonym request

Comment: [tag:standards-compliance] should just be removed and those questions should be retagged with [tag:standards] IMO.

Comment: Yeah, we should find a standard tag to use.